# Get DataTable values from anywhere on Excel spreadsheet using OleDB/Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, oledb

I have a simple business requirement to design a "Roster" spreadsheet that can be read by a powershell script to extract out data for down stream processes. The spreadsheet has some headers such as FirstName, LastName, Company, StartDate. These headers start on A1 and continue to J1. The spreadsheet is 2007 (xlsm) and contains 1 worksheet with a formatted Table (DataTable?). To the right of the DataTable are a few fields such as NumberOfRecords and ContactInfo.

The powershell script so far works fine as long as the DataTable is the first column/row. If I were to switch the NumberOfRecords & ContactInfo field above or to the left, then it throws off the whole order of record reading.

Below is the current script

```
function getData {
$excelPath = "c:\temp\Roster.xlsm"
$global:roster = @()

$conn = new-object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = 'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='+$excelPath+';Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";'

$cmd = new-object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Roster$] WHERE [Valid] = true",$conn)
$conn.open()

$reader = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
while ($reader.Read())
{
    $user = new-object object
    $user | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "FirstName" -Value $reader.item(1).ToString()
    $user | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "MName" -Value $reader.item(2).ToString()
    $user | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "LastName" -Value $reader.item(3).ToString()
    $user | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Company" -Value $reader.item(6).ToString()
    $user | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $reader.GetName(8) -Value $reader.item(8).ToString()
    $global:roster += $user
}

$conn.close()

$global:roster | out-gridview
#
}
```

Is there any way I can reference this DataTable directly? I know in Excel 2010 when formatting data as a table you can give it a name (default Table1). Could I do something like `"SELECT Table1.* FROM [Roster$] WHERE [VALUE] = true"` ??

My goal is to give a nicely formatted spreadsheet, extracting the data from the formatted table via Powershell.

Comment: going out on a limb and maybe this isn't useful, but I would think you would have to name the datatable in the excel, than your generated SQL would work. To confirm, you can name data tables in 2007 as well.

Comment: I followed the example from Microsoft:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316934. I renamed the Table to MyNamedRange, however when I try and run the reader I get the: Exception calling "ExecuteReader" with "0" argument(s): "The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object
 'MyNamedRange'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'MyNamedRange'
 is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator."
The query I use is "SELECT * FROM [MyNamedRange]"

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but it requires using COM instead of OLEDB or ADO. I was not able to find any solution online with OLE to call named objects. This solution is a bit better since I can arrange my DataTable anywhere in the worksheet, however I'm not too fond of it since it requires Office to be installed, but basically I can call reference to the Named Table by creating an Excel object and then calling it's ListObjects on the ActiveSheet. This returns the DataTable with all of it's Columns/Rows/Ranges. All I need to do then is loop through each row and column to grab the data.

```
$excel = new-object -ComObject Excel.Application
$tmp = $excel.Workbooks.Open('c:\temp\Roster.xlsm')
$table = $excel.ActiveSheet.ListObjects | where-object { $_.DisplayName -eq "MyNamedRange" }    
$rows = $table.ListRows
```